# Path to my background images on IOS8 iphone or How to recover my background's images from my iphone

Tags: iphone, graphics, path

I made a great picture and place it as background at my iphone , now i cannot find it anymore at my camera roll.
I need this picture that is still as my backgroud image. Just give me route or a path or an program to recover it, and NO, is not at any of my backups any more...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you don't want to jailbreak your phone there are a number of utilities that let you browse through the backup of your iPhone and locate files, messages, voicemail and a whole bunch of other stuff.

Though I have not used it one of the top search results is [iExplorer](http://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/). And it is cross platform.

There may be better ones but this says it works on Macs and PCs and you didn't say what you had.